# I think I am getting closer in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a logistic regression model but I keep on getting error messages on when I try to create it.

Here is my sample code:

```
proc logistic data = cleaned_anes descending;
  class default / param=glm;
  model default = student balance income;
run;
```

It says my variables are not found. But they are in my excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Please post the message verbatim. Model variables (`default`, `student`, `balance`, `income`) must be contained in specified data: `cleaned_anes`

Comment: I am so sorry I am not sure what you mean? I am still new to SAS. Could I see an example?

Comment: Whether they're in your excel sheet is inconsequential. Proc logistic is not reading your Excel sheet. It's reading the dataset you imported from the Excel sheet. Are they in your dataset you specified for proc logistic? Open your dataset and view what variables you have available. If not, correct your import and ensure your variables are in the data.

Comment: Hey Stu I have three variables: student balance income